# Add 'active' Class to PanelSnap panel

Tags: jquery

I'm using https://panelsnap.com. I need to add an `active` class to the current panel.

I made the plugin work with some custom options but I'm not able to make the callbacks work. I guess I should use the `addClass()` function to the `snapStart` callback but I may be doing something wrong. This is how the structure should be:

```
on([string] eventName, [function] callbackFunction(panel))
```

This is my working code without adding the class so far

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var options = {
    container: document.body,
    panelSelector: '.snapp',
    directionThreshold: 100,
    delay: 0,
    duration: 300,
  };

  new PanelSnap(options);
});
```

[EDIT]

Your code is working but not with `$(this)`,  instead if I add the class selector it applies to all elements. Is there a way to do it with `each` for example?

My new code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var options = {
    container: document.body,
    panelSelector: '.snapp',
    directionThreshold: 100,
    delay: 0,
    duration: 300,
  };

  var psInstance = new PanelSnap(options);
  psInstance.on('snapStart', function() {
    $('.snapp').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from all other panels
  }); 
    psInstance.on('snapStop', function() {
    $('.snapp').addClass('active'); // add the class to the current panel.
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you need to hook to the `snapStart` event on the instance of `PanelSnap()` that you create in order to add the class. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var options = {
    container: document.body,
    panelSelector: '.snapp',
    directionThreshold: 100,
    delay: 0,
    duration: 300,
  };

  var psInstance = new PanelSnap(options);
  psInstance.on('snapStart', function(panel) {
    $('.snapp').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from all other panels
    $(panel).addClass('active'); // add the class to the current panel.
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks @rory-mccrossan The callback is working great, but still have some issues. I edited my question again.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the documentation. I though the callback runs under the scope of the active panel, but instead it's passed as a parameter. I've updated the answer for you